# Составляем списки навыков

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, документация

### Вступление

Технологий много, возможностей же у них еще больше, поэтому очень важно знать, что в них является
основным, а что второстепенным, что нужно и не нужно знать новичкам, и где та черта, которая разделяет
новичка от профессионала.

Такие знания помогают экономить время всякому, кто решил освоить какую-либо технологию или профессию,
ибо он будет знать с чем ему необходимо ознакомиться в первую очередь, а что может подождать. Ведь никто же
не станет пробовать построить надёжный мост без предварительного знания физики, геометрии и прочих
фундаментальных вещей, хотя зачастую подобная ситуация не редкость, к сожалению.

Итак, что за инструмент в этом деле нам может помочь? Предлагаю использовать **список навыков**.

### Что такое список навыков и для чего он нужен?

1. Для того чтобы упорядочить знания, рассортировать их по важности и сложности, а самое главное
   показать все ключевые характеристики  по какой-либо технологии, профессии и т.п.
2. Применительно к данной площадке, он позволит **увеличить количество задаваемых вопросов**. Например, некто прочитал в perl-списке (см. пример в ответах), про пункт "Понимать связывание с помощью оператора tie." и после того, как этот некто не смог найти доступной информации по данной теме, он мог бы задать вопрос вида: "Как использовать tie в perl?". Без списков же про tie он мог бы вообще и не узнать, и не только он.

### Строение списка навыков

- Заголовок: наименование технологии, профессии и т.п.
- Разделение на три уровня сложности: начальный, средний и продвинутый,
- где каждый уровень непосредственно состоит из списков навыков и знаний по данной технологии.

### Пример Perl-списка

#### Начальный

- Понимать суть переменных $_ и @_
- Уметь создавать объект с помощью bless.
- Уметь создавать и вызывать функцию.

  - Анонимную.
  - Именованную.
- Уметь поключать и настраивать модули.
- ...

#### Средний

- Написать и выложить свой модуль на CPAN.
- ...

#### Продвинутый

- Сделать коммит в perl?!
- ...

### Как его использовать на ruSO?

По аналогии со списками книг, т.е. создаётся вопрос с метками: [название технологии][список-навыков], затем пишутся ответы к нему, которые соответственно редактируются и дополняются всем сообществом.

Всего ответов может быть в количестве от одного до трёх, т.е. либо в одном ответе все три уровня знаний, либо если список будет получаться весьма большим, то его можно разделить на два или три, в зависимости от количества уровней, так как вполне возможно что для некоторых технологий достаточно двух уровней или вообще одного начального.

Так же необходимо будет создать общий вопрос, в котором будут ссылки на все существующие списки.

В общем, всё как с книгами, только немного практичнее.

### В каких случаях могут быть полезны списки навыков на ruSO?

По поиску "[должен знать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C)" отобрал несколько вопросов к которым, в качестве ответа на вопрос, можно было бы давать ссылку на список по конкретной тематике:

- [Настоящий джангист](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/297834/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82)
- [Собеседование по алгоритмам - как подготовиться к нему за одну неделю?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/307629/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8E/310414#310414)
- [Что должен уметь системный администратор?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/11281/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80/11458#11458)
- https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/385147/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F/385149#385149
- [Должен ли тестировщик знать unit-test фреймворки?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/120198/%D0%94%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-unit-test-%D1%84%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8/120240#120240)
- [Насколько надо изучающему C++ знать C. Лучший учебник по C++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/161933/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-c-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-c-%D0%9B%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE-c/162280#162280)
- [Что должен знать начинающий веб разработчик?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/274440/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B1-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)

Пример perl списка в ответе сделал общим, можете улучшать его или же написать в ответе свой собственный вариант списка по любой интересной вам технологии.

Comment: сортировка знаний по важности и сложности - дико субъективная вещь, даже в рамках одной технологии.

Comment: Обратили внимание, сколько тем в Вашем списке `должен знать` закрыто? Что думаете делать, чтобы и новые *спинизы* не постигла та же участь?

Comment: Я только за. За все формы представления знаний  и умений. Эта похожа на вроде бы разрешенный сомовопрос-самоответ, так что может и примут (скорее, если такие темы будут *общими*).

Comment: @edem ок, вы привели примеры того, что можно считать базовыми знаниями, и даже между ними уже есть сомнительные зависимости (структуры данных для изучения циклов и функций не нужны). как вы предлагаете сортировать вещи на базовые и не очень? и, тем более, на средний или продвинутый. Особенно в языках, которые поддерживают сразу несколько платформ. Например, куда отнести знание о double buffering-отрисовке в WinForms (C#). это сложнее или легче знания о том, как организован кэш в asp.net (C# опять же!)?

Comment: @edem кстати, почти все вопросы, которые вы привели - это древний оффтопик. Половина уже была закрыта, вторую половину я закрыл только что - на такие вопросы можно дать красиво выглядящий ответ, но он будет дико субъективным. Например - Должен ли тестировщик знать unit-test фреймворки? - большая часть тестировщиков не знает unit-test фреймворки и прекрасно без этого живет. Более того, есть области тестирования, которые вообще не подразумевают автоматизацию (тестирование UX, например) - но специалисты в которых дико ценятся. А теперь сходите со ссылке и почитайте принятый заплюсованный ответ :(

Comment: @edem это я к тому, что спиниз по тестированию, будет дико спорным. как и спиниз по любой более-менее широкой области. А если он не будет спорным - то будет неактуальным и бесполезным.

Comment: @PashaPash вы слишком цепляетесь к сортировке, абстрагируясь от цели: (1) Сортировка литературы по проф. уровню - тоже априори субъективная вещь, но это не мешает существовать **самим** спискам литературы. (2) ТС не полагает, что закрытые вами вопросы **хороши** для сообщества, в текущем виде, иначе не предлагал бы альтернативу им. (3) Лично моё мнение, - некоторые вещи проще возглавить и организовать, чем с ними бороться. Вопросы, вроде "С чего мне начать изучение языка XXX", были есть и будут, сам такие когда-то задавал (правда, не здесь).

Comment: Можел лучше СНИЗ? :)

Comment: @andreycha наши западные коллеги [оценили бы ваш вариант](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/sneeze) :)

Answer (score 18):

С одной стороны, мне **нравится** эта идея. И на ruSO есть всё необходимое для **сбора информации**: открытость, модерация, сообщество. К тому же, конечной целью вопрошающих в подобных поисках обычно являются не крупные источники знаний, а какие-то достижимые точки в навыках.

---

С другой стороны, это **полумеры**. Вопрос надо решать масштабнее, и предлагаемое решение закроет лишь половину того, что нужно: сбор информации. Остаётся показать эту информацию в виде, который будет пригоден для конечных пользователей.

*// Эту тему я решил развивать отдельно **[на гитхабе](https://github.com/D-side/skillforest/)**.*

Представление такой информации в виде списка это натягивание данных на неподходящую им структуру. Но более сложные варианты на платформе StackExchange тяжелореализуемы.

У представления в виде списка с разделением довольно много проблем:

- У списка неминуемо есть порядок, сверху вниз, котому не всегда можно придать смысл, но он будет видеться, потому что список *очень* абстрактный и (по идее) каждой своей деталью что-то означает
- Разделение на "три уровня" довольно условно и размыто
- Трудно представить отдельные *ветви* развития в пределах профессии, и её связь с другими ветвями.

На мой взгляд, такие вещи стоит представлять в виде **ациклического ориентированного графа** (необязательно дерева!) (вроде [вот такого](http://bl.ocks.org/rkirsling/5001347)):

[image: ориентированный граф]

...где отдельные навыки зависят друг от друга (стрелочка от навыка указывает на то, для чего он нужен). Вот прям визуально. Чтобы "зависимые" появлялись только при наведении или включении всех "зависящих" узлов (а-ля "это я могу/этому я научился"). К каждой вершине такого графа можно приложить краткое описание и источники знаний по теме.

Этим решаются все перечисленные выше проблемы:

- Когда граф "резиновый", порядок в нём не ощущается, а где он важен, он есть
- Уровень "начальный".."эксперт" перестаёт быть условным и выражается в расстоянии от "свободных точек", но явно при этом не обозначен
- Ветви представляются вполне себе натурально и могут иметь связи между собой

Но это больше годится в качестве **открытого программного проекта** (на GitHub или где-то ещё), хотя это вполне может быть "проект-компаньон" к данным, собранным здесь. Но собирать здесь данные о структуре таких графов... будет крайне неудобно, по причинам выше, и эти ответы будут, по сути, бесполезны для людей, смысл из них будет извлекать *программа*, и уже её вывод будет информацией для людей. Оставим это самому проекту и обычным способам вклада open-source-сообществ.

**Давайте всё-таки остановимся на сборе информации, хорошо представимой списками.** Да, StackExchange хорош для публикации многих видов информации, но всё же **не всех**.

---

- PS: у меня эта неделя выдалась богатой на изобретение велосипедов, возможно, такой продукт уже существует, просто я о нём не знаю. На гитхабе, я видел, собирают "awesome lists [of awesome lists]", но не более.
- PPS: отдельный челлендж: свести множество таких схем из нескольких источников данных в одну. Чтобы, условно, кто-то один вёл ветку по "архитектуре и проектированию ПО", а кто-то другой ссылался на отдельные точки из неё, а клиент подгружал данные обеих и показывал сведёнными вместе. На манер того, как это делает проект [Federated Wiki](http://fed.wiki.org/).
- PPPS: гипотетически... я мог бы даже этим заняться. По сути, достаточно подготовить Jekyll-шаблон, который будет выводить данные из YAML и визуализировать с помощью JS. Гитхаб будет перестраивать датасет при каждом пуше самостоятельно. [Подобное я уже делал](https://github.com/D-side/geekparty4). <s>Но CORS, для федеративности, там нет.</s> ([есть](https://twitter.com/invisiblecomma/status/575219895308324864)) А чтобы не привязываться к конкретной реализации, стоит это дело специфицировать с оглядкой на построение других визуализаторов и расширения наборов данных.

---

Очередной мозговой штурм привёл к [интересной мысли](https://github.com/D-side/skillforest/issues/4#issuecomment-311831133): в использовании такой инструмент будет очень похож на [системный менеджер пакетов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8).

- Сначала человек указывает что уже знает (отмечает как уже установленное).
- Затем он замахивается что-то изучать (даёт команду на установку).
- Система строит ему [топологически упорядоченный](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0) список навыков/концепций, которые он должен изучить (в pacman это *транзакция*). Этот список, фактически, получается персональным планом обучения.

Поскольку системные менеджеры пакетов уже давно и успешно используются в бою, можно ряд идей позаимствовать у них. В частности, то, что касается распределённости, отношений между пакетами и разрешения конфликтов.

Comment: Я бы предложил строить такие графы на основе статей Википедии, там уже есть для этого все данные (статьи с ссылками друг на друга). Готовые графы, кстати, можно было бы вешать в  описание меток.

Comment: @Risto к сожалению, одна статья Википедии плохо соответствует отдельной точке на графе такого назначения хотя бы потому, что по каждому языку программирования, за редким исключением, точка всего одна.