# Опрос про необходимость списка навыков

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, опрос

Идея была описана в данном вопросе ["Составляем списки навыков"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2790/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%8B). На данный момент у неё +7 голосов, у самого же примера, который в ответе - 0 голосов. Т.е. не совсем понятно, пользователи за или нет, поэтому дабы прояснить ситуацию предлагаю провести опрос по этой теме.

P.S. В комментариях пишите Ваши мысли по этому поводу.

#### Обновлено

На данный момент сообщество не заинтересовано в данном функционале по меткам, так как по результатам голосования, со счётом **13/9** (количество проголосовавших за определённый вариант "За" и "Против" соответственно, а остальные варианты досрочно выбыли из соревнования), побеждает вариант "Против списка навыков".

Comment: Возможно, вы не заметили, но у вас уже есть 1000 репы, поэтому вы можете просматривать количество проголосовавших "за" и "против", если нажмёте на оценку поста. По-моему, результаты очевидны.

Comment: @Discord спасибо не знал. Что касается того вопроса (+9/-5) как по мне ничего очевидного. На примере же (+2/-5) чуть поочевиднее, конечно.

Comment: Скажем так, с такой пропорцией протестующих, в числе которых ещё и модератор, шансы на успех невелики. :D

Comment: Просто никто не знает перл, поэтому длинный ответ лень читать. Будь там пример для си или джаваскрипта, было бы лучше.

Comment: @Qwertiy их можно добавить, как пример, в ответах. Чем больше примеров, тем нагляднее будет идея.

Comment: Голосую против, только потому, что само слово "Спиниз" звучит неприятно.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Списки навыков не нужны на этой площадке.

Answer (score 4):

Списки навыков нужны в том виде, в котором они были предложены.

Answer (score 1):

*4 вариант*

Ничего не имею против списка навыков, но они не вписываются в формат ВиО. Пусть будут в вики меток.

Comment: Есть метка "книги" она отвечает на вопрос "Что почитать?", а могла бы быть ещё метка "спиниз", она отвечала бы на вопрос "Что нужно знать и уметь?". В общем-то тот же формат ВиО, только чуть более полный. По поводу меток. Рассматривал такой вариант, но у него есть существенный минус - это скорость: правки по меткам ожидают по несколько дней для того, чтобы их подтвердили, да и не факт, что подтвердят.

Comment: @edem Мне по душе более прикладной SO, поэтому я против мета-меток и вопросов из серии "что нужно уметь, что почитать, какое кино посмотреть и т.п.".

Comment: Это Ваше предпочтение, но обобщать до "какое кино посмотреть" это конечно перебор.

Comment: @edem Уверен, если покопать, то найдется немало документальных фильмов и видео по IT и у них тоже могут быть свои сторонники, как и у книг, например. *идея спинизов мне нравится, но как показывает голосование, она здесь не очень приветствуется в предложенном фомате*

Comment: Можно неинтересные метки добавить в "чёрный список".

Answer (score -6):

Списки навыков нужны, но как обычный список навыков и знаний, **без** разделения на уровни сложности: начальный, средний, продвинутый.

Comment: Без разделения они не только здесь не нужны, но и вообще нигде.

Comment: @Qwertiy ну обычно они встречаются чуть ли не в каждой книге по программированию, только называются по другому - "Содержание" ;)

Comment: Содержание является упорядоченным и неявно предполагает последовательное чтение с увеличением сложности. А в предложенном там варианте есть деление на категории. Т. е. вариантов два - либо забиваем на категории и делаем упорядоченный список по которому можно учить подряд, либо делим на категории, но поверх них на уровни. Да и вообще, на мой взгляд, с уровнями список полезнее.