# Сборник фольклора Stack Overflow на русском

Tags: обсуждение, предложение, вопросы

Бывает, кто-то задаёт смешной вопрос ну совсем не по теме сайта. Этот вопрос закономерно удаляется. Но содержимое его ещё долго обсуждается и вспоминается в чатах, становится источником только нам понятных шуток и местных мемов.

Мои фавориты:

- Что делать, если с пацанами бухали весь семестр, а теперь исключают.
- Как придумать фальшивую историю, чтобы притвориться сирийцем и уехать в Европу.
- Выучил за лето C++, теперь неясно, зачем нужны другие языки.

## Собственно, [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Составить и пополнять список таких вопросов в удалённом вопросе на Мете.

> Цель: возможность развлечь себя чтением весёлых вопросов.

Почему в удалённом: потому что сами вопросы тоже будут удалены. Нет смысла показывать оглавление, если книга недоступна.

С другой стороны, оглавление будет мотивировать на то чтобы набрать 10к и увидеть-таки удалённые вопросы.

> **НЕ цель**: высмеивание личностей авторов вопросов.

Задача довольно рискованная, потому что можно скатиться в высмеивание и оскорбления. Поэтому давайте будем осторожны.

- Вопрос обязательно анонимизируется, чтобы не компрометировать автора.
- Вопросы активных участников (с > 1 репутации или > 1 вопросом) не трогаем.
- Если есть риск обидеть участника, тоже не добавляем.

> За - ставьте плюс вопросу, против - ставьте минус. Всё как обычно )

### Алгоритм добавления

предлагаю такой:

1. Предложение озвучивается и обсуждается в чате. (Не нужно засорять этим Мету).
2. Голосуем, например, [звёздочками на сообщениях](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32141158#32141158) с текстом "Смешно" и "Не смешно".
3. Если предложение принимается, то

   1. Модератор дополняет список (модераторы могут редактировать удалённые вопросы)
   2. При наличии в вопросе любой чувствительной или деанонимизирующей информации модераторы редактируют ревизию (т.е. историю правок)
   3. Просим CM анонимизировать вопрос (не путайте со "сделать общим"). В результате анонимизации автором вопроса становится Дух сообщества, любые ссылки на автора исключаются.
   4. Удаляются комментарии от автора или обращённые к автору.

### Вероятная польза от сборника весёлых вопросов:

1. Хорошие примеры плохих вопросов
2. Пристанище усталого путника и отдых от вопросов про [жуквери-плюгины](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b6%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%8b)
3. Повод набрать 10000 репутации
4. Вечная слава безымянным героям
5. Способ сбросить напряжение, чтобы не перегореть и не уйти с сайта

### Возможный вред:

1. Акцент на высмеивании, а не на помощи новичкам
2. ... дополняйте.

Это предложение уже неоднократно обсуждалось в чате, в последний раз - [вчера, тоже довольно весёлым образом](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32140898#32140898).

Comment: `Бывает, кто-то задаёт смешной вопрос ну совсем не по теме сайта. Этот вопрос закономерно удаляется` - бывает по теме вопрос еще смешнее а комментарии к ним вдвойне. вспомнить одного светлова стоит и его клонов

Comment: Люто заплюсовал бы, но увы, это кажется уже выходит за рамки вежливого отношения к другим участникам. Минус.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский удалённые комментарии нельзя почитать, а оставлять их ради анекдота мы не будем, пожалуй.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian вопрос будет анонимизирован, ссылки на участника в нём не будет.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я добавил ещё пару соображений о том, как остаться в рамках. Если у вас есть возражения или предложения - добавляйте. http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/3667/revisions

Comment: Можно дать авторам выбор, запретив добавление в этот список вопросов, удалённых **самими авторами** (не модераторами).

Comment: @D-side, тогда проще спросить у самих авторов - не хотят ли они увековечится в "Кривом зеркале SO"?

Comment: @Other если автор сам осознает, что накосячил, он сам же удалит вопрос. Мне кажется, что явно спрашивать излишне. Можно предупредить о моменте начала голосования в чате комментарием к вопросу типа "Вопрос номинирован на внесение в <базу анекдотов?> StackOverflow на русском. Правилами ведения <базы анекдотов?> запрещено вносить вопросы, удалённые самими авторами. Если вы против того, чтобы ваш вопрос в <ней?> фигурировал, удалите его сами до того, как это сделают модераторы." И, не знаю, сутки на обдумывание, пока идёт голосование в чате.

Comment: @D-side, т. е. использовать то, что я предложил - механизм опроса автора.

Comment: @Other фактически да, просто ответ неявный.

Comment: @D-side звучит угрожающе)

Comment: Но меня ещё беспокоит другая деталь. Мне нравится идея. По-моему, я её даже когда-то предлагал. НО. Не увеличится ли от этого число закрываемых/удаляемых вопросов в сообществе из-за тех, кто вознамерился попасть в этот "зал славы"?

Comment: @D-side *кружок то по интересам* и если быть честным доступен далеко не каждому

Comment: @D-side, опрос именно хомячков просто так не проведёшь. О этом вопросе и дискуссии в чате знают только местные гики, а основные генераторы бреда не знают о участи. Может они были бы против?

Comment: @Other потому я и предлагаю оставлять под вопросом комментарий с вышеприведённым текстом. Чтобы узнали.

Comment: @D-side, это уже когда примут эту идею и начнут реализовать. А на этапе обсуждения хомячков нет.

Comment: @Other а что её реализовывать? у каждого есть свои сборники

Comment: @Other это, конечно, касается процедуры принятия в список **новых** вопросов. Остаётся вопрос, что делать со старыми, да.

Comment: Ну и таки что дальше?

Comment: @andreycha похоже, сборнику мемов - быть, а списку удалённых шедевров - нет.

Answer (score 15):

## Реализовать в форме сборника мемов и фольклора, а не вопросов.

Пример: [The Many Memes of Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta), там есть ссылки на сборники отдельных сайтов.

Плюсы:

- Фольклор рождается не только в необычных вопросах, но и в чате, на Мете, на встречах участников, вообще везде где есть сообщество.
- Можно обойтись совсем без ссылок на вопросы и их авторов.
- Акцент на описании субкультуры сообщества, а не на обсуждении участников.
- Можно объяснить разные непонятные термины, например рассказать о хелп-вампирах.
- Решает задачу "почитать что-нибудь развлекательное, не выходя с сайта".

## Кстати, уже реализовано.

Сохранение всех подозрительных вопросов в сети Stack Exchange уже реализовано.

Есть неофициальная система автоматического распознавания спама. Если не вдаваться в подробности, она включает в себя:

- Демон SmokeDetector, читающий содержимое всех новых и отредактированных сообщений через SE API.
- База данных Metasmoke, в которой для целей проверки, аргументации и чего угодно ещё **сохраняются тексты всех сообщений**, на которые сработала проверка.
- Чатбот для управления системой через чаты SE.

Так вот, если заглянуть в Metasmoke, то можно занять себя увлекательным чтением вопросов, в том числе удалённых, отсортированных по категориям для удобства. База доступна всем, а не только пользователям с 10к.

---

Это интернет, в нём нет анонимности.

Comment: Электронную почту тоже боты читают, но пока это делает бот, которому фиолетово на аспекты типа "О, пакажу пацанам, поржём!", можно быть спокойным.

Answer (score 7):

Прежде чем рассматривать за и против, необходимо понять, *какую проблему мы пытаемся решить данной инициативой*? Возможно, есть ли другие, более эффективные способы решения поставленной задачи.

Какова задача?

---

По инициативе

#### Против

Интересная инициатива, с одной стороны. С другой, она может превратиться нечто противоречащее основополагающим идеям сообщества о равноправном и уважительном отношении участников друг к другу.

- Казалось бы, на что обижаться, если ты опубликовал забавное сообщение. Более того, его сделали анонимным. Но ведь автор то все равно знает, что сообщество потешается над его сообщением! Возможно, в его глазах оно не выглядит так уж смешно.
- Человек пришел на сайт за знаниями, опубликовал вопрос. Вопрос закрыли и удалили, вырвали отдельные фразы и повесили на всеобщее обозрение ради собственной потехи. Вряд ли изучающий прийдет снова...
- ...и придет кто–либо вообще. Движок сайта – это самая простая часть проекта. Сообщество – наиболее сложная его часть, основная.
- Мы с вами сами создаем окружение, в котором взаимодействуем. Прежде чем опубликовать свой первый вопрос, новый участник должен преодолеть несколько психологических барьеров. Например, побороть страх быть отвергнутым сообществом коллег, что может крайне негативно сказаться на самооценки и ассоциации себя с профессией.
- Stack Overflow – место решения профессиональных задач, а не клуб юмористов. В сообществе необходимо поддерживать атмосферу знаний. Шутки разрушают ее: согласитесь, если в библиотеке разрешат проводить утренники и корпоративы, она перестанет быть библиотекой, местом, куда приходим за знаниями.
- Все мы разные: то, что для одного смешно, может вызывать грусть у других.
- Модераторы не могут выступать в роли «рефери», так как не являются профессионалами комедии. Их выбрали модераторами, так как коллеги сочли их одними из лучших специалистов программирования, которым не безразлична судьба русскоязычного сообщества разработчиков.
- Уверен, в Интернете уйма примеров плохих вопросов. Было бы здорово, если бы было побольше хороших примеров.

Если так случилось, что вопрос задан в комичной манере, следует не потешаться над ним, а объяснить автору, в чем его ошибка. Очень бы хотелось, чтобы сайт был привлекателен как для новых участников, так и для старых, именно знаниям, а не шутками.

Comment: 1. в предложении не говорится о вырывании фраз из контекста как Вы предполагаете. 2 речь идет о заброшенных обезличенных вопросах/ответах не активных участников. 3. ограничение в виде 10к репы тоже далеко не всеобщее обозрение

Comment: Ну, реакция вполне ожидаемая и справедливая. Отмечу только фактически неверные детали: (1) никакого вырывания фраз из вопросов, а публикацию на всеобщее обозрение осуществляет сам **автор вопроса** в первую очередь, а ограничение на 10к+ репутации для просмотра весьма существенно; (2) *если в библиотеке разрешат проводить утренники и корпоративы, она перестанет быть библиотекой* - было бы неплохим сравнением, если бы в библиотеку мог кто угодно отдать любое произведение собственного авторства, и даже при этом: знаниями же у нас являются в основном ответы, а вопросы лишь средство их сортировки.

Comment: Полностью поддерживаю. Почти все эти доводы я тоже приводил в той или иной форме.

Comment: @Bald Если будет задача создания набора анекдотов, то с большой вероятностью может браться лишь забавная их часть. На мой взгляд, не важно заброшенный или нет вопрос, важно отношение к людям. Ограничение в 10К делает все еще хуже, люди даже не будут видеть, что над ними потешается небольшая элитарная группа.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но тут следует понимать что и не принятие данного решения никоим образом не означает что *некая элитарная группа* не будет высмеивать некоторые вопросы. альтернатива: удалил так удалил, т.е. после удаления вопрос/ответ виден максимум только модераторам сообщества(и то сомнительно)

Comment: `Но ведь автор то все равно знает, что сообщество потешается над его сообщением` - множества авторов таких вопросов и участников с 10к репутации не пересекаются.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky ...и поэтому если кто-то и будет этим заниматься, то это должно быть не связанное с сообществом официально третье лицо, и делать это тихо. Ни на что не намекаю :)

Comment: @D-side, вот только Серого кардинала нам ещё не хватало.

Comment: `коллеги сочли их одними из лучших специалистов программирования` - по моему опыту, модерация держится целиком на коммуникативных навыках и почти не требует навыков программирования. Более того, я точно не являюсь одним из лучших специалистов.

Comment: @Bald Не будет, так как текущие нормы морали сообщества этого не позволяют, а нарушения «[кодекса дружелюбия](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)» приводит к ограничению доступа к сайту вне зависимости от репутации и статуса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky сначало это должно быть выявлено... а если в *узком кружке* что никто не узнает что Вы предлагаете делать? только если кто то проявит гражданскую сознательность не иначе...

Comment: @NickVolynkin Не соглашусь. Модерация требует обширных знаний программирования и рядом лежащих технологий. Если бы вы не были знатоком, за вас бы не голосовали на выборах. Коммуникативность, конечно же нужна, но без знаний предмета никак.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky думаю, что Ник имел в виду то, что он не является "одним из лучших специалистов **по программированию**". Когда имелись в виду высокие коммуникативные навыки и *достаточная* техническая подготовка.

Comment: @Bald Вся идея Stack Overflow построена на сознательности и неравнодушии друг к другу.

Comment: @D-side да, именно об этом речь. Модератор должен быть с высокими навыками коммуникации и стрессоустойчивости и хотя бы не чужд IT. Пример тому - CM испанского или итальянского SO, профессиональный менеджер сообществ и не программист.

Comment: Категорическое "против" возможно только в случае, если движок будет поддерживать физическое удаление и будет удалена прерогатива видеть удалённые сущности. И то, найдут мнительные индивиды, которым будет плохо уже от факта того, что люди помнят тот пост... мы дойдём и до стирания воспоминаний участников? Поэтому сразу говорить "нет" инициативе только потому что её хлопотно реализовывать и она сопряжена с трудностями -- как-то неубедительно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin Речь идет о модераторах от сообщества, не управляющих сообществом.

Comment: @NickVolynkin предполагаю, что вы просто не совсем верно интерпретировали фразу Николаса: она про то, что вы "специалист" (неважно, насколько хороший: вы как минимум *в целом, в теме*), и "один из лучших по годности в модераторы участников". По отдельности. Но в одном лице. Совместное употребление этих признаков странно комбинируется языком в единое целое **не то** :)

Comment: особо упёртые сами себя увековечат в сети, а глупости, смешные и не очень, все периодически выдают, независимо от статуса, опыта и возраста.

Answer (score 2):

## Нереализуемо (если держаться за выбранные ценности)

#### Официально подобный архив фольклора существовать не будет (при нынешних обстоятельствах).

В [ответе Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3669/181100) сказано, почему. Думаю, это можно считать чётким **нет**.

Но теперь появились предпосылки для его создания инициативными третьими лицами на сторонних (возможно, разработанных специально для этой цели) ресурсах. [A K](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/213987/a-k) отметил, что *фольклоризация* в сообществе неминуемо *будет происходить*.

**Серьёзно, давайте предположим, что зелёный свет на неофициальный список фольклора на всех фронтах дан и рассмотрим техническую сторону вопроса.**

*Заранее замечу, что **не собираюсь этим заниматься сам** (на мне до сих пор висит [skillforest](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2793/181100) и ремонт), но считаю нужным высказать ряд вещей, которые необходимо предусмотреть, дабы это не ударило (или хотя бы ударило как можно слабее) по сообществу.*

**tl;dr: ...но неофициально, похоже, ресурс тоже не состоится, т. к. технические требования для него удовлетворить без вмешательства SE (команды StackExchange), скорее всего, не удастся. И *единственной* жизнеспособной для этого платформой является сам SE.**

Сие потенциальное поделие я обозначу, как "архив".

1. Не надо публиковать в нём контент, а если публиковать, то с проверкой на наличие доступа на SE. Что странно и дублирует функциональность SE. Проще публиковать исключительно ссылку и, возможно, заголовок (их же надо как-то находить в архиве).
2. **Не стоит публиковать** в архиве ссылки на **вопросы, которые были удалены их авторами**. Если автор удалил вопрос сам, это его выбор, и мы должны его уважать.

   - ...если это не вандализм и не уничтожение ценных знаний. Да, можно развести демагогию и объявить анекдоты ценными знаниями, жечь которые тоже вандализм. Но серьёзно, все стороны понимают, что довод притянут за уши. Если нужно, можно притянуть за уши и доводы против него. Сложно ожидать продуктивной дискуссии в подобной ситуации.
3. Стоит **предусмотреть механизм отзыва вопросов из архива их авторами** (даже если вопрос был удалён модераторами), вроде того, что действует по [DMCA](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Millennium_Copyright_Act). К сожалению, надёжно определить авторов подобных вопросов путём авторизации через SE может быть невозможно технически, т. к. авторы таких вопросов с немалой вероятностью могут быть не зарегистрированы вовсе. Как их опознать тогда?

   - Можно, конечно, запретить публикацию ссылок на вопросы от *авторов без возможности идентифицировать*. Но есть опасения, что архив будет в результате почти пустым, ведь многие вопросы, достойные попадания туда, это первые вопросы участников на ресурсе. А чтобы публиковать здесь вопрос, даже регистрация не требуется.
   - Плюс сталкиваемся с необходимостью *знать автора вопроса*, от которого предложение как раз требует отказаться. Ой-вэй.
   - Я не изучал технические детали, может, есть какие-то трюки, которыми можно опознать даже незарегистрированных. Но боюсь, без вмешательства команды SE (чего ждать не стоит) это неосуществимо.
   - С этим превосходно бы справилась **наша система тревог**, которая может установить идентичность личностей тревогнувшего и автора вопроса, если не сама, то хотя бы при поддержке модератора.
4. *Загрузка...*

Comment: Нереализуемо (как сторонний ресурс) именно из-за того, что вряд ли кто возмется за эти хлопоты. Все остальное (согласия, несогласия, правила ...) это ерунда.

Comment: @avp я примерно об этом же. Можно наплевать на все ограничения и судьбы авторов, агрессивно собирать информацию об авторах и выкладывать тексты вопросов публично. Это технически очень просто! И это как раз просьба дважды подумать перед тем, как за это браться.

Comment: Технически реализуемо, есть же http://www.stackprinter.com/. Можно даже написать бот автоархивирования. Вопрос скорее тут насчёт forced privacy, но с этим больших технических проблем я не вижу.

Comment: @VladD, а нет никакой privacy. Есть лицензия, по которой автор отдает свой пост на SO.

Comment: @Nofate лицензия нам не мешает. Нет никакой проблемы приложить ссылку на первоисточник. Беспокоят последствия исключительно с точки зрения... не знаю... человечности что ли.