# Насколько легален "цитатный" чат?

Tags: поддержка, чат

Я бы хотел уточнить, насколько легален т.н. ["цитатный" чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50845/)?

Когда год назад обсуждалось его создание я слышал опасение, что администрация сайта будет против его создания — идёт вразрез с правилом [будьте дружелюбными](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice). Тогда я впервые и услышал мем про "чтение анекдотов", хотя возможно он и раньше существовал.

Я не особо помню, чем кончилась эта [история](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/32158837#32158837) — у меня был перерыв на сайте на несколько месяцев. Когда вернулся — чат живой, иногда туда постят разные истории многие участники. А, вот [тема на мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3667/213987) нашлась.

Можно ли это считать признаком того, что чат легален? Знает ли администрация про его существование, считает нормальным факт его существования? Не могу понять, поэтому спрашиваю на мете.

Comment: Да нормально там всё, цитаты - они и есть цитаты... Arhad вот меня давече цитировал - нарушило ли это be nice?

Comment: Комментарии удаляются, забываются, а тут коллекция наиболее интересных в одном месте.

Comment: Если вопрос/ответ/комментарий не нарушает правил SO, значит и цитата не является нарушением, надеюсь.

Answer (score 8):

Раз никто не высказывается, выскажусь я.

Разумеется, чат легален. Публикация цитат не может быть нарушением чего бы то ни было, ведь автором цитаты является другой человек, и, следовательно, если и исправлять, то исходную проблему.

По поводу офтопичности (не о программировании), можно считать цитатный чат принадлежащем Мете — а тут он, как и любое обсуждение сайта, онтопик.

Comment: возможный вред от цитат, если злобный человек собирает: все люди, все ошибаются -- чат ошибку подсвечивает, насмехается и делает её вечной (публично для всех  доступной навсегда). Поэтому индивидуальная privacy важна и существуют такие понятия как "право быть забытым".

Comment: @jfs: Почему бы и нет? Исключения имеют смысл, да: если кто-то хочет удаления своих цитат, удалим. Но обычно собираются безобидные смешные истории, так что введение исключения не ничему повредит.