# Книга сообщества, или Руководство по изучению технологии

Tags: обсуждение

Коллеги, хочу поделиться с вами мыслями, как помочь людям осваивать новые технологии.

> ### Кратко
>
> На Stack Overflow запрещены общие вопросы, хотя они очень востребованы как у новичков, так и у тех, кто их закрывает. Было бы здорово вместе проработать такие вопросы, по аналогии с вопросами о литературе, не «сломав Stack Overflow».

Stack Overflow — лучший друг и помощник разработчика в момент, когда что–то пошло не так и *проблема в той или иной степени известна*, ее можно сформулировать либо в виде запроса к поисковику, либо в виде вопроса на сайте. Совершенно иначе выглядит ситуация, когда мы только хотим приступить к изучению чего–то нового, неизвестного для нас. В этом случае возникает две основные проблемы:

1. Мы не знаем того, чего не знаем: крайне затруднительно сформулировать запрос к поисковику о неизвестной нам на данный момент технологии.
2. У нас отсутствует необходимый кругозор для адекватной оценки ситуации и выбора правильной технологии. Непонятно, с чего начинать.

Самое обидное здесь то, что даже если мы всем сообществом [соберем достаточно объемную базу знаний об основных аспектах различных технологий и лучших подходах в программировании](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6419/), это не решит проблему получения экскурса в новую технологию для того, кто с ней не знаком, так как о существовании самих технологий и подходах необходимо как–то узнать! Проблема курицы и яйца, которая решается только временем: вы найдете знания, если вы знаете, что они существуют и именно они вам и нужны, а для этого необходимо обладать каким–то базовым пониманием.

### Книги, курсы и университеты

Чтобы получить эти базовые знания, кругозор и эрудицию в предметной области, наше общество ввело такие институты, как: университеты, курсы дополнительного образования, книги, самоучители и т.д. Все они дают нам базу необходимых теоретических знаний, чтобы мы могли начать ориентироваться в основах дисциплины и выбрать специализацию для более узкого профессионального развития.

Действительно, если кто–то хочет переквалифицироваться, например, из Java–разработчика в C++–разработчика (или, что более наглядно, из, скажем, художника в Java–разработчика), существует проверенный путь — пойти в университет, записаться на курсы или освоить самоучитель по С++! Хотя лично я часто использую подход с книгой, он имеет существенные недостатки:

1. Огромная потеря времени на повторяющиеся знания (цикл for везде цикл for).
2. Получаемые знания носят чисто теоретический характер, их сложно сопоставить с имеющимися прикладными задачами, трудно объединить несколько уроков и упражнений во что–то единое.

Как говорится, в теории — теория и практика одинаковы, однако на практике это не так. Вероятно, поэтому мы видим большое количество общих вопросов, в которых не всегда можно найти сам вопрос: людям непонятна практическая сторона теории, неясно, в какую сторону, с чего начать. Это проблема не только новичков, но и многих опытных специалистов, начинающих изучать что–то новое.

#### Как примерно могут выглядеть руководства: предлагаемая структура

Спланировать оптимальный вид заранее достаточно сложно. Мы будем изменять правила в процессе реализации. Начать можно следующим образом:

1. Все такие вопросы и ответы к ним должны быть общими. Это дает возможность уйти от зависимости от одного составителя (например, как у книг). Надеюсь, всем сообществом мы сможем обозначить лучший путь, чем могли бы по отдельности.
2. Вероятно, оптимальным будет формат один вопрос — много ответов, где вопрос есть «глава» книги, посвященной метке, ответы в вопросе — «параграфы главы».
3. Содержание вопроса — основная мысль, рассматриваемая в ответах, и оглавление по параграфам.
4. Каждый параграф — ответ — объяснение подраздела руководства на конкретных примерах, где примеры — конкретные вопросы на Stack Overflow. Ссылки на вопросы в ответах — ключевая особенность: параграф должен основываться на нескольких реальных вопросах на Stack Overflow. Содержание ответа — лаконичное последовательное раскрытие основных важных идей с отсылкой к конкретным вопросам–примерам на сайте.
5. Руководства (вопросы) следует отмечать специальной меткой, чтобы их можно было найти по основной метке, например, [javascript] или [wpf], и специальной метке, например, [руководство].
6. Несколько руководств мы сведем в «книгу» в описании метки. Способ сведения — от простого к сложному: если новое руководство подразумевает знания из какого–другого, оно должно идти ниже в списке (в случаях циклических зависимостей право выбирать остается за автором).

### Зачем нам нужны «книги сообщества» на Stack Overflow?

Наличие таких вопросов даст нам возможность улучшить следующие аспекты нашего сообщества:

1. Появится возможность закрывать наиболее популярные общие вопросы как дубликаты, а не как общие, тем самым предоставляя автору вопроса те знания, за которыми он пришел в сообщество.
2. Многие участники не раз говорили, что хотели бы принять участие в рассмотрении подобных общих вопросов. У вас появится эта возможность!
3. Изучение нового раздела знаний станет куда более эффективным, чем до этого. Все, что будет необходимо, — сделать выборку по языку или технологии, плюс метка [руководство], изучить интересующие особенности на примерах и сразу начать разрабатывать проект! В пределе было бы здорово создать способ получения знания, не уступающий по глубине книгам, по ширине — вузам.

Как результат, мы вместе сделаем знания, по большому счету платные до сегодняшнего дня (курсы, вузы, книги), бесплатными, а значит и более доступными большему количеству людей!

### Как и с чего начать

На мой взгляд, индикаторами для написания нового руководства могут служить следующие события:

- Вы хотите изучить, изучаете, недавно изучали или просто видите необходимость в «общих» знаниях, объединяющих в одно логически целое несколько вопросов на Stack Overflow.
- Появляется большое количество однотипных общих вопросов на данную тему, которые закрываются.

### Научим друг друга!

Созданные обществом институты — результат имеющихся на момент создания потребностей и возможностей. У нас существует уникальная возможность создать новый институт, который подразумевает взаимное обучение: больше никаких профессоров–зазнаек, ненужных знаний и непонятно зачем поступивших в вуз или на курсы студентов–двоечников!

Мы можем вместе, без большой нагрузки на отдельно взятого человека, составить лучший из возможных учебных курсов по конкретно взятой технологии или языку! Вкладывая на входе чуть-чуть, каждый участник обмена знаниями получает на выходе намного больше, чем имел до!

Возможен ли мир, где каждый из нас одновременно и ученик, и учитель кого–то другого — зависит только от нас!

Если у вас есть коллега, который готов помочь окружающим узнать что–то новое, пожалуйста, поделитесь с ним этой публикацией и попросите его разместить хотя бы немного знаний в открытый доступ: либо в виде руководства, либо [отдельным вопросом](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6419/). Возможно, в будущем, именно эти знания помогут именно вам быстро запустить «проект выходного дня» или устроиться на новую работу!

### Инициатива — дело общественное

Собрать подобную базу знаний не по силам одному человеку, как и задать оптимальные процессы. Пожалуйста, поделитесь вашими мыслями по теме, предложите ваши улучшения, инициативы! Ваши мысли и идеи крайне важны и очень нужны сообществу! Вместе мы намного больше, чем просто сумма отдельных индивидуумов.

---

**Обновление**, по результатам диалога в [чате сообщества](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--).

**В**: Стоит ли просто расширить тематику сайта, разрешив общие вопросы вида «какую библиотеку посоветуете», «лучший способ отрисовки диаграмм» и т.д?

**О**: Идея в том, что бы не расширять тематику сайта. Вместо этого, мы добавляем исключение: при необходимости, силами сообщества создать один общий вопрос на какую–то одну тему, и рассмотреть его последовательно в несколько ответов, если это требуется.

Инициатива — не есть предложение расширения тематики, а скорее предложение в рамках существующих правил, с небольшим шагом в сторону, добавить полезное всем содержимое. Для этого, например, необходимо лишь создать один общий вопрос с несколькими ответами, раскрывающими разные подходы в разных (конкретных!) условиях. Имея такой вопрос, все вопросы о «лучших библиотеках» можно будет закрывать дубликатами, так как в «общем руководстве сообщества» будут даны рекомендации о наиболее распространенных случаях.

---

**В**: В чем отличие подхода обозначенного в данной инициативе от подхода с расширением тематики сайта?

**О**:

1. В рамках инициативы, на сайте всегда будет лишь один вопрос на одну конкретную тему, общий. Расширив тематику сайта, мы получим множество более или менее одинаковых вопросов, трактовать однозначно которые (то есть закрывать дубликатами), смогут только авторы.
2. Ответов к такому вопросу будет несколько, каждый из которых будет «однозначным», так как будет рассматривать проблему с одной конкретной стороны, то есть с заданными условиями, которые введет автор ответа, дописав, при необходимости, вопрос.

   3. В случае, например, появлению новых технологий или подходов, относящихся к вопросу, можно будет добавить новый ответ или исправить существующие.
   4. Вопрос и ответы к нему будут поддерживаться всем сообществом.

Проблема вопросов, закрывающихся как «слишком общие» в том, что любой ответ на них и правильный, и не правильный одновременно, потому что в них отсутствуют конкретные детали. Эти детали, из автора вопроса, вытянуть практически невозможно, так как во многих случаях автор сам их не знает, так как только приступает к изучению. Если такой вопрос пишется знатоками, они знают все о выбранной теме и могут поделить ее на конкретные логические единицы и рассмотреть их по отдельности (в разных ответах).

---

**B**: Это будет ну очень большой Q&A. По факту, нужно будет написать добротную статью, а то и почти книгу. И для этого нужно иметь очень большой опыт в выбранном вопросе, либо делать в несколько человек и при этом затратить ещё больше времени на согласование ответов.

**О**: Не обязательно сразу писать книгу. Можно начать с чего–то малого, например, если взять конкретный слишком общий, все время повторяющийся вопрос и дать на него несколько ответов в предложенном формате — это будет прекрасное начало! Те, кто посчитают, что у них достаточно знаний, смогут дописать ответы, переписать сам вопрос.

Нет никакой спешки! Поделимся тем, что знаем. Придут новые участники и поделятся чем–то еще. В этом и есть уникальность обучения у сообщества: это не работа одного человека, и не нужно никакой согласованности в мышлении авторов, каждый привносит что–то свое.

Comment: А не смахивает ли это недавно закатившуюся Документацию?

Comment: @alexolut Нет, это не документация, хотя, возможно, какие–то механики могут быть похожи. Существует очень много идеологических отличий. Например, идеологически, хотелось бы иметь какое–то небольшое число «руководств» по каждой метке, в которых бы раскрывались основные моменты. В инициативу не входит покрытие всех нюансов отдельной технологии. Инициатива много ближе к общим вопросам про литературу, чем к Документации.

Comment: «из, скажем, художника в Java–разработчика» — здесь, кстати, художник должен как-то узнать, что Java и другие языки программирования вообще существуют :) // «цикл for везде цикл for» — [зануда] есть как минимум два совершенно разных «for (a; b; c)» и «for a in b» [/зануда]

Comment: А вообще с сутью согласен. А на английском SO что-нибудь такое делалось/обсуждалось?

Comment: @andreymal На сколько мне известно, именно в таком виде ребята вроде бы ничего не делали.

Comment: Не зря справа в похожих этот вопрос показан https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2790/Составляем-спинизы Идея жива.

Comment: @edem СПИНИЗы, на мой взгляд, все–таки, немного о другом. Согласно текущей инициативе, ответы должны состоять из реальных пояснений, большая часть из которых, по возможности, должна быть дополнена реальным примером — вопросом с ответом на Stack Overflow. Это не список, это полноценный ответ.

Comment: Ну просто если идёт речь о книге, как таковой, то у неё должно быть содержание, а эту роль они вполне могли бы на себя взять. Впрочем это уже вопрос терминологии лишь.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, отличная идея. Я правильно понял, что в принципе должны получиться *интерактивные*, постоянно расширяемые "книги", материал в которых вероятно может быть связан ссылками?

Comment: @avp Совершенно верно! Причем, «книга» начинается с _одного вопроса_, а затем эволюционирует в процессе добавления новых вопросов и ответов в существующие вопросы.

Comment: @edem Содержание, возможно, будет здорово иметь где–то в описании метки, к которой пишутся руководства. Да, такое содержание, вероятно, очень–очень похоже на СПИНИЗ. Немного отдаленным примером может быть [описание метки JavScript на Stack Overflow на английском](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info).

Comment: Да, но многое упирается в репутацию, это многим связывает руки, даже если им есть что сказать. Отдельный вопрос/ответы был бы более динамичным вариантом, как мне думается, с возможностью комментирования, обсуждения и редактирования для гораздо большего количества участников.

Comment: не достижимо, к сожалению. Разве что платить за каждую главу, иначе интерес исчезнет так и не появившись.

Answer (score 4):

То, что вы описали, можно было бы сделать с помощью Документации.

Обучение без наставника малоэффективно. Я говорю так не потому, что хочу завалить вашу идею или покритиковать, а потому, что действительно так думаю. Очень много нюансов, которые вот на кончиках пальцев, как сказал бы Гейтс, понимаете. Которые важны, но их либо очень много и нет смысла описывать потому, что никто это не будет читать, а проще показать. Либо спецы к ним так привыкли, что считают самими собой разумеющимися, что забывают о них говорить. А многие, когда видят, что человек не монимает эти тонкости, еще и крутят у виска, это мы наблюдаем и здесь, хотя и стремимся от этого избавиться. Вы можете сказать, что для этих нюансов СО и создавался. Я отвечу, что СО эту задачу не достаточно хорошо решает, вы сами об этом по сути пишете, давайте будем откровенными.

Для эффективного обучения нужен наставник, который, если нужно, возмет ученика за руку (или шкирку :) и будет его водить и показывать все на пальцах. Плюс к этому не стоит забывать, что обучение это отдельная квалификация, можно быть хорошим спецом, но плохим учителем. То есть недостаточно просто вывалить факты и ссылки, это должен быть учебный материал, он должен быть соответсвующим образом оформлен и преподнесен.

Что же качается обмена знаниями, то я только за. Только важно не делать вид, что это обучение, пусть и самостоятельное. Так как это повлечет "политические" проблемы для сообщества из-за того, что это якобы обучение не будет работать. Называть это следует обменом знаниями между равными. Пусть это будет конференция, симпозиум, форум, что угодно, но не обучение.

Comment: Это не Документация, но какие–то механики похожи. Инициативой, мы стараемся улучшить процессы для людей, которые уже приняли решение изучать программирование самостоятельно (как дополнение, к обучению на курсах или полностью самостоятельно, например, в случае переквалификации из C++ в Python–разработчика). Полноценное изучение книг, во многих таких случаях, избыточно, так как человеку требуется какие–то базовые знания, чтобы начать, а не всеобъемлющие знания языка, которые уже от части есть.

Comment: Обновил публикацию вопросами и ответами из чата. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, Мне кажется, они адресуют несколько затронутых вами тем.

Comment: @Cerbo, мало того, что нужен наставник, так ещё и само обучение должно происходить в процессе разработки реальных программ, чтобы у ученика появилось понимание применимости и, как результат, возможность анализа эффективности того или иного инструмента в каждом конкретном случае. То есть просто ходить и показывать пальцем не получится, надо дать прочувствовать плюсы, минусы и особенности каждого подхода и средства «в бою».

Answer (score 4):

Для обучения какому-либо предмету нужна программа изучения предмета. Разные люди видят эти программы по-своему. Например, кто-то считает, что ООП надо изучать на примере С++, кто-то думает, что лучше с Objective-C. И вот таким разным людям вы хотите доверить написание одной методички или руководства по чему-либо.
Википедия — хороший справочник, но вот учить что-то по ней очень неприятно. Как раз из-за коллективного характера контента. А вы хотите сделать что-то типа википедии или викиучебника.

Comment: Да, вы совершенно правы (о намерениях). Мне кажется, подход, когда разные люди предлагают разные подходы к одной задаче в одном месте очень и очень хорош. Только так мы сможем увеличить свой кругозор ([про это я писал в соседней публикации](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6419/)). К слову, я в свободное время изучаю базовую математику, в том числе по Википедии. Когда я хочу разобрать какой–то аспект, я нахожу 5 — 10 ссылок по теме и читаю их по очереди. По материалам  одного автора разобраться самостоятельно очень сложно.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky смотря какой автор, вот например mathprofi.ru, очень доходчиво объясняет тему.

Comment: @edem Mathprofi.ru — лучший сайт по математики из всех мне известных. Я даже у него задачки приобретал (были бы пожертвования, я бы сделал). Это скорее исключение, чем правило. Любая тема, не рассмотренная на этом сайте занимает очень много времени.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky согласен, доступнее объяснение материала не попадалось ранее. Вот страница для "Спасибо" у него, кстати: http://www.mathprofi.ru/scripts/call.html А так да, чем больше авторов участвует в объяснение материала, тем выше вероятность наткнуться на талантливого препода.

Comment: @edem Спасибо за ссылку!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky да не за что!

Comment: Ну а в чём проблема описать несколько подходов одновременно? Тот подход, который наиболее популярен автоматически станет более полным, т.к. больше народу будет задействовано. Не вижу проблемы.

Comment: Начинающим будет очень тяжело разобраться со всеми этими подходами в пределах одного руководства. Надо упрощать материал, а не усложнять его.

Answer (score 2):

Простите, если моё предложение не совсем корректно. Но мне видится, что оно в русле того, что предлагается сделать. Итак, предлагаю использовать такой формат познания как реализация какого-либо проекта "с нуля" с помощью сообщества в тех местах, в которых исполнитель зашёл в тупик.

Поясню. Например, проект "Извлечь с помощью языка Python из PDF-газеты все объявления и разместить на сайте". Это общая глобальная задача. И далее её реализация по пунктам. Первое — с помощью библиотеки парсинга из PDF извлекаем весь текст из газеты. Результат — ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ. Второе — очищаем от мусора извлечённый текст с помощью регулярных выражений. Результат — ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ. Третье — Каждое объявление из одного большого извлечённого текста помещаем в файл в виде отдельной строки. Результат — НЕ ПОЛУЧИЛОСЬ. И вот здесь обращаемся к сообществу с вопросом, как решить эту подзадачу.

Все этапы снабдить примером кода и описанием стоявшей задачи (в предлагаемом формате с описанием проблем не будет, любой участник будет видеть логику проекта в целом). И вот таким образом дойти до результата. И вся цепочка решений станет наглядным пособием. Любое звено из этой цепочки или несколько звеньев или большая совокупность будет ответом на какие-либо вопросы пользователей в рамках языка Python. Да и в целом те, кто только приступает к этому языку, благодаря такому подходу увидят какие задачи и как решает этот язык. А по аналогии с этими конкретными решениями новичок сможет найти решения и для других задач.